# Undirected graph conversion to tree

Tags: graph, tree, graph-theory, nodes

Given an [undirected graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undirected_graph#Undirected_graph) in which each node has a Cartesian coordinate in space that has the general shape of a tree, is there an algorithm to convert the graph into a tree, and find the appropriate root node?

Note that our definition of a "tree" requires that branches do not diverge from parent nodes at acute angles.

See the example graphs below. How do we find the red node?

[image: Example input graph]
[image: Example output tree]

Comment: In this example undirected graph, any node could be taken as the root, and you'd get a proper tree.  If I got it right, which node will be the root depends on the spatial arrangement of the nodes.  But it's not clear to me how, and what you mean by "branches do not diverge from parent nodes at acute angles".  Can you clarify?  Can you explain e.g. why the topmost or rightmost node can't be a root for your application?

Comment: @paniwani: do you mean that angles between branches linking siblings to their (common) parent node must not be acute ? do you have any data structure to work on beyond coordinates and graph structure ? apart from the degree of the root node, will your trees be binary ? binary trees would be easier to process as exactly 1 of 3 angles between adjacent edges is acute, so parent/child-relationships could be determined locally.

Comment: @paniwani: note that your problem seems to be ill-defined: consider any steiner tree; there are **no** acute angles between branches at all. therefore any node could be chosen as a root node without violating your constraint

Comment: can't every node be root of a tree depending on how you look at the graph?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

here is a suggestion on how to solve your problem.

### prerequisites

- notation:

  - `g` graph, `g.v` graph vertices
  - `v,w,z`: individual vertices
  - `e`: individual edge
  - `n`: number of vertices
- any combination of an undirected tree g and a given node g.v uniquely determines a directed tree with root g.v (provable by induction)

### idea

- complement the edges of `g` by orientations in the directed tree implied by `g` and the yet-to-be-found root node by local computations at the nodes of `g`.
- these orientations will represent child-parent-relationsships between nodes (`v -> w`: `v` child, `w` parent).
- the completely marked tree will contain a sole node with outdegree 0, which is the desired root node. you might end up with 0 or more than one root node.

### algorithm

assumes standard representation of the graph/tree structure (eg adjacency list)

1. all vertices in `g.v` are marked initially as not visited, not finished.
2. visit all vertices in arbitrary sequence. skip nodes marked as 'finished'.
   let `v` be the currently visited vertex.

   - 2.1 sweep through all edges linking `v` clockwise starting with a randomly chosen `e_0` in the order of the edges' angle with `e_0`.
   - 2.2. orient adjacent edges `e_1=(v,w_1), e_2(v,w_2)`, that enclose an acute angle.
     adjacent: wrt being ordered according to the angle they enclose with `e_0`.

     [ note: the existence of such a pair is not guaranteed, see 2nd comment and last remark. if no angle is acute, proceed at 2. with next node. ]

     - 2.2.1 the orientations of edges `e_1, e_2` are known:

       - `w_1 -> v -> w_2`: impossible, as a grandparent-child-segment would enclose an acute angle
       - `w_1 <- v <- w_2`: impossible, same reason
       - `w_1 <- v -> w_2`: impossible, there are no nodes with outdegree >1 in a tree
       - `w_1 -> v <- w_2`:
         only possible pair of orientations. `e_1, e_2` might have been oriented before. if the previous orientation violates the current assignment, the problem instance has no solution.
     - 2.2.2 this assignment implies a tree structure on the subgraphs induced by all vertices reachable from `w_1` (`w_2`) on a path not comprising `e_1 (`e_2`). mark all vertices in both induced subtrees as finished

       [ note: the subtree structure might violate the angle constraints. in this case the problem has no solution. ]
   - 2.3 mark `v` visited. after completing steps 2.2 at vertex `v`, check the number `nc` of edges connecting that have not yet been assigned an orientation.

     - `nc = 0`: this is the root you've been searching for - but you must check whether the solution is compatible with your constraints.
     - `nc = 1`: let this edge be `(v,z)`.
              the orientation of this edge is v->z as you are in a tree. mark v as finished.

       - 2.3.1 check `z` whether it is marked finished.
                     if it is not, check the number `nc2` of unoriented edges connecting `z`.
                         `nc2` = 1: repeat step 2.3 by taking `z` for `v`.
3. if you have not yet found a root node, your problem instance is ambiguous:
   orient the remaining unoriented edges at will.

### remarks

1. termination:
   each node is visited at max 4 times:

   - once per step 2
   - at max twice per step 2.2.2
   - at max once per step 2.3
2. correctness:

   - all edges enclosing an acute angle are oriented per step 2.2.1
3. complexity (time):

   - visiting every node: O(n);
   - the clockwise sweep through all edges connecting a given vertex requires these edges to be sorted.
     thus you need `O( sum_i=1..m ( k_i * lg k_i ) )` at `m <= n` vertices under the constraint `sum_i=1..m k_i = n`.

     in total this requires `O ( n * lg n)`, as `sum_i=1..m ( k_i * lg k_i ) <= n * lg n` given `sum_i=1..m k_i = n` for any `m <= n` (provable by applying lagrange optimization).

     [ note: if your trees have a degree bounded by a constant, you theoretically sort in constant time at each node affected; grand total in this case: `O(n)` ]
   - subtree marking:
     each node in the graph is visited at max 2 times by this procedure if implemented as a dfs. thus a grand total of `O(n)` for the invocation of this subroutine.

     in total: `O(n * lg n)`
4. complexity (space):

   - `O(n)` for sorting (with vertex-degree not constant-bound).
5. problem is probably ill-defined:

   - multiple solutions: e.g. steiner tree
   - no solution: e.g. graph shaped like a double-tipped arrow (<->)

Comment: Damn.. I was looking for the opposite of the OP's question but this nails it. Well explained, well documented. Great answer. (Old post, I know)

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to define a 2d rectangle around the red node or the center of your node and compute each node with a moore curve. A moore curve is a space-filling curve, more over a special version of a hilbert curve where the start and end vertex is the same and the coordinate is in the middle of the 2d rectangle. In generell your problem looks like a discrete addressing space problem.